# Свой код в скомпилированной программе

Tags: ассемблер, elf, linux

Есть ELF файл в линуксе, в неком месте есть call внутренней функции, как добавить в программу свою функцию и поставить ее вызов вместо существующей функции? И еще объясните как работает call, как высчитывается смещение вызова? Сама программа огромна, примерно 130к функций, есть ли какие-то методики для поиска в программе неиспользуемоего кода, куда можно вписать на ассемблере свой код?

P.S. примерно знаю как делается инжект в виндовсе, но всё равно если можно то по-подробней об этом всём.

Answer (score 1):

Заменить "штатную" функцию на свою можно. Для этого существует ни один инструмент. Не знаю, как в линуксе, но в Windows это можно сделать под 32-битным отладчиком, например, есои программа 32-битная, конечно же! Отладчик называется OllyDbg. Для линукса не знаю - не работал с отладчиками в этой системе. Но уверен, их также немало - поищите!

Объясню, как работает инструкция call. Она базируется( скорее всего, во всех современных процессорах ) на банальной смене текущего адреса текущей инструкции на адрес, по которому лежит точка входа в вызываемую функцию. Это сделать очень легко через регистр EIP, почитайте. И далее "идет" по инструкциям, что далее той точки входа, пока не встретит точку возврата результата - RETN. А эта инструкция, в свою очередь, берет верхушку стека, в которой находится этот самый адрес возврата( куда возвращать результат и после "прыгать" ). Этот адрес всегда следует после того адреса, откуда была вызвана функция.

Объяснил хоть и не "супер-пуперовскими" терминами, но по-любому должно быть понятно =)

**Удачи!**

Comment: В 32битных системах обычно используются ближний и короткий вызовы (call near и call short) (ну еще косвенный вызов - переход по адресу, значение которого лежит в регистре или где-то в памяти), операндом при таких вызовах фактически является разница между адресами команды следующей после call и команды, на которую производится переход, для near эта разница умещается в 4 байта, для short - в 1. Поэтому здесь дело не в "банальной смене адреса", а в банальной арифметике с адресами:)

Comment: Я даже вопрос задавал по теме: [Как узнать адрес блока в вызове call](http://hashcode.ru/questions/108119/как-узнать-адрес-блока-в-вызове-call).